# xvfb-run with melt hangs

Tags: kdenlive, xvfb

I am using melt utility to flatten vidoes. in it there is a plugin called kdenlivetitle. this plugin imposes title text on video but it requires X server. for that i am using xvfb-run but it hangs in-between sometime. I know basic linux and script writing. below is the output of "ps"

```
    root@ip-10-112-249-15:/home/ubuntu# ps -ef| grep melt
root      5632 32532  0 03:44 ?        00:00:00 sudo /usr/local/scripts/melt_title.sh /usr/local/tomcat/temp/231/composition.mlt EXP_temp.mp4
root      5633  5632  0 03:44 ?        00:00:00 sh /usr/local/scripts/melt_title.sh /usr/local/tomcat/temp/231/composition.mlt EXP_temp.mp4
```

//melt_title.sh has command which running belove

```
root      5634  5633  0 03:44 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -e /var/log/xvfb.log --server-args=-screen 0 1920x1080x24 melt /usr/local/tomcat/temp/231/composition.mlt -consumer avformat:EXP_temp.mp4 acodec=aac ab=384k ar=48000 vcodec=libx264 g=10
root      5650  5634  0 03:44 ?        00:01:17 melt /usr/local/tomcat/temp/231/composition.mlt -consumer avformat:EXP_temp.mp4 acodec=aac ab=384k ar=48000 vcodec=libx264 g=10
```

could it be because of this command running simultaniously simultaneously? if it is i can restrict it to one at a time.

if you require any of other log or output please provide me how to get it.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used Xdummy instead of xvfb and it worked like a charm
Download Xdummy scrip [Xdummy script](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/Xdummy)

run it like this

```
Xdummy :99 -geometry 1920x1080x24
```

then you can run melt or any gui application headless using

```
DISPLAY=:99 melt
```

or

```
DISPLAY=:99 firefox
```

Comment: Can you give more detail on how you did this?

Comment: We used Xdummy script instead of xvfb because it was in consistence

Comment: I just answered the question in the original reply because I wanted to add links and code.